# How to set two different splash screen?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, splash-screen, ionic-native

How can i set two different splash screens according to package name.

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
  translate.setDefaultLang('az');
  translate.use('az');
  statusBar.hide();
  splashScreen.hide();
    localStorage.setItem('companyKey', this.companyToken);
    this.appVersion.getPackageName().then(packageName => {
        if(packageName.indexOf('app.business') > -1) {
            this.rootPage = LoginPage
        } else if(localStorage.getItem('selectedTags')) {
            this.rootPage = LandingPage;
        }
    });
}
```

I can only check package name when platform is ready.